# Execute Ruby files from a HTML page in non IE

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, html

I have a bunch of code written in Ruby. I want to develop a web page which can run these scripts.
Is there a way to execute ruby files from a web page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute ruby scripts **IN** browser - you can use ruby compiled with https://github.com/kripken/emscripten - scripts will be executed in a page with some limitations like no filesystem access or no threading, also highest version of ruby will be 1.8.7 (for example, like here http://codechat.net/)

If you want to run scrpts **FROM** browser via http - you can use CGI (or similar technologies)
For example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_web_applications.htm
You will need some wrapper to add valid http headers to script output

Comment: Basically, I am trying to execute the scripts on a click of a button from the html developed. Executing with the help of batch files is not an option as its not supported by Chrome and firefox.

Comment: so you want to avoid http server? Just run directly from browser?

Comment: I think sinse NPAPI is phased out and now only option to run external programs is https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging , easier way is to use http server for scripts run